# Exclude NULL values from selection tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, null

I have a table that is containing data for a month

```
SELECT 
       CASE WHEN (m1.is_internal = 1 AND m2.is_internal = 1) THEN
            SUM(CAST([size] AS BIGINT)) END AS internal_volume,
       CASE WHEN (m1.is_internal = 0 AND m2.is_internal = 1) THEN
            SUM(CAST([size] AS BIGINT)) END AS external_volume_in
FROM 
       messagesgal msg
LEFT JOIN 
       messages_addresses m1
       ΟΝ msg.originator = m1.address
LEFT JOIN 
       messages_addresses m2
       ΟΝ msg.recipient = m2.address
WHERE 
       date >= 43179
GROUP BY 
       floor(date), m1.is_internal, m2.is_internal
```

This query gives me the following result:

[image: query_result]

I would like to exclude the appearance of NULL values on this selection.
Why it gives me NULL values in case i want to get only these big integers and how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe if you add `date` to select statement you get the answer

Comment: There is coalesce function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected output

Comment: Add `internal_volume IS NOT NULL AND external_volume_in IS NOT NULL` into your `WHERE`? Expected results are unclear.

Comment: `floor(date)`? What is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `NULL` values because you are filtering your sums on the column expression and not on your `WHERE`. The both `NULL` records are those where `is_internal` isn't 1, so both `CASE` won't match it's `WHEN` and return default of `NULL`, instead of calculating the `SUM()`.

Try filtering your "not internal" records on your `WHERE` like the following:

```
--...
WHERE 
       date >= 43179 AND
       m2.is_internal = 1
GROUP BY 
       floor(date), m1.is_internal, m2.is_internal
```

You can then remove the additional condition from your `CASE`. Also I find a `SUM(CASE...)` easier to read.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN m1.is_internal = 1 THEN CAST([size] AS BIGINT) END) AS internal_volume,
SUM(CASE WHEN m1.is_internal = 0 THEN CAST([size] AS BIGINT) END) AS external_volume_in
```

In general terms, if you want to filter results of a query by their column's value (if they are complex expressions and you don't want to repeat them in the `WHERE` or the `HAVING`), you should try to move them to a subquery or CTE and filtering afterwards:

```
;WITH Results AS
(
    SELECT 
           CASE WHEN (m1.is_internal = 1 AND m2.is_internal = 1) THEN
                SUM(CAST([size] AS BIGINT)) END AS internal_volume,
           CASE WHEN (m1.is_internal = 0 AND m2.is_internal = 1) THEN
                SUM(CAST([size] AS BIGINT)) END AS external_volume_in
    FROM 
           messagesgal msg
    LEFT JOIN 
           messages_addresses m1
           ΟΝ msg.originator = m1.address
    LEFT JOIN 
           messages_addresses m2
           ΟΝ msg.recipient = m2.address
    WHERE 
           date >= 43179
    GROUP BY 
           floor(date), m1.is_internal, m2.is_internal
)
SELECT
    R.*
FROM
    Results AS R
WHERE
    R.internal_volume IS NOT NULL OR
    R.external_volume_in IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a filter that excludes Null and using [Coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) function:

```
SELECT 
       Coalesce(CASE WHEN (m1.is_internal = 1 AND m2.is_internal = 1) THEN
            SUM(CAST([size] AS BIGINT)) END, 0) AS internal_volume,
       Coalesce(CASE WHEN (m1.is_internal = 0 AND m2.is_internal = 1) THEN
            SUM(CAST([size] AS BIGINT)) END, 0) AS external_volume_in
FROM 
       messagesgal msg
LEFT JOIN 
       messages_addresses m1
       ΟΝ msg.originator = m1.address
LEFT JOIN 
       messages_addresses m2
       ΟΝ msg.recipient = m2.address
WHERE 
       date >= 43179 and internal_volume IS NOT NULL AND external_volume_in IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
       floor(date), m1.is_internal, m2.is_internal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
case when m2.is_internal = 1 then 
    case m1.is_internal when 1 then 'internal volume'
                        when 0 then 'external volume in'
    end
end [type],
case when m2.is_internal = 1 then 
    case m1.is_internal when 1 then SUM(CAST([size] AS BIGINT))
                        when 0 then SUM(CAST([size] AS BIGINT))
    end
end [value]
```

Then you could wrap it in outer query, where you would select values, where `[value] is not null`.